# Graph editor numbers

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I have a problem with proportions of my graph editor, on the right side of the picture is how it looks and on the left side is how it suppose to look, the problem as you can see is with the proportions of the axes as you can see on the right side frames goes up to around 120 and the height/y axis it goes up to 100 while on the it goes up to only 10. Because of that my graph is very flat and is very hard to work with, is there any setting so i  could fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the graph editor, you can use Ctrl MMB to resize the graph by moving either left ↔ right or up ↔ down:

[image: demo gif]

You can also press the <kbd>home</kbd> button to frame everything.

There are a bunch of other view options, you can see them all under the view menu:

[image: view menu]